# Why does system asks for encryption passphrase the INACTIVE user when mounting encrypted external drive?

Tags: 20.04, encryption, xfce, external-hdd, automount

When I am the only user logged to my laptop (XFCE session), mounting encrypted portable HDD works as expected:

1. I connect HDD to USB port.
2. A window asking for encryption passphrase pops up.
3. I enter the passphrase.
4. The HDD is mounted and file manager window appears.

However when another user is also logged (in another XFCE session; screen locked), the window asking for encryption passphrase pops up in their session.  I have to unlock their session to enter the passphrase.

Moreover, if the other user wants to mount an encrypted HDD, they need to enter the encryption passphrase in my session as well as my login credentials in their session (to authorize the operation).

I think it is pretty ridiculous.  What is the reason behind popping encryption passphrase window in the inactive session?

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify which "password" is admin permission (like to mount the external device), and which "password" is the decryption passphrase (for access to the data). Suggest using a different term for each. Is your shared (thus non-private) date really sensitive enough for encryption?

Comment: The username is not of importance. It is the UID. The password for the user with UID 1000 is the one it asks for IF you set it such that admin needs to give permission. Things to do/check: put all those users in the same group and set the mount so it is owned and executable (ie. mode: x7x) for that group. And then all can mount in that group.

Comment: @Rinzwind Why should I elevate privileges of the other user?  I want the "HDD password" window popping up in my XFCE session, not their.

Comment: @user535733 Done.  I cannot believe you are asking me whether I need to use a certain system feature...

Comment: @abukaj Use of unclear or confusing terms instead of accepted conventions suggests (not proves) inexperience. Thus a question about underlying assumptions is appropriate. Sometimes those assumptions are valid. Sometimes not.

Comment: @user535733 There is plenty of reasons someone may need to use encrypted portable drives - from GDPR implementation in company to paranoia to borrowing a movie collection from a paranoid friend.  Regarding accepted conventions: I have just checked.  "Password" and "passphrase" are used interchangeably in that context https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/disk-encryption-luks

Comment: Thank you for clarifying your question.